# How do I call a specific function from another python file with an input

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a specific function from a python file called `calls.py` with a specific input in `main.py`

I first made this file called `calls.py`

```
#calls.py

def caller1():
    print('called 1')

def caller2():
    print('called 2')

def caller3():
    print('called 3')
```

I then tried in a different file called main.py to call a specific function with an input

```
#main.py


#import the calls.py file as ca
import calls as ca


#create array of commands to call functions
commands = {}
commands['call1'] = ca.caller1()
commands['call2'] = ca.caller2()
commands['call3'] = ca.caller3()


#take input for a command
inpt = input('call a function: ')


#check if inpt is equal to one of the commands and run the corresponding function
if inpt in commands:
    commands[inpt]()
else:
    print('unknown command')
```

Whenever I run main.py instead of waiting for an input to use a specific function in `calls.py`, it just uses all functions at the same time when running `main.py`.

Comment: just change to `commands['call1'] = ca.caller1`,not call it.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is running the function and assigning the result (`None`) to `commands['call1']` and the remaining commands. What you want is to assign the function itself to `commands['call1']` like so:

```
commands = {}
commands['call1'] = ca.caller1
commands['call2'] = ca.caller2
commands['call3'] = ca.caller3
```

Note there are no parenthesis.

`ca.caller1()` calls the function. `ca.caller1` is the function.

Now to call the function you can use

`result = commands['call1']()`